# C++: std::copy esque function for mapping values of one vector to another

Tags: c++, std

Suppose I start with:

```
std::vector<double> obj_values(obj_iterable.size());

for(int i= 0; i < obj_iterable.size(); i++)
    obj_values[i] = obj_iterable[i].value
```

And instead I would like to write (in pseudo-code):

```
// Pseudo code
std::map_onto(obj_iterable.begin(), obj_iterable.end(), obj_values.begin(),
              [](Obj & x){ return x.value; });

// etc.
```

This seems like something that should exist somewhere in the standard library, but I am not finding it, and would want to avoid templating to handle `unordered_set`, `unordered_map`, `deque`, etc. if I were to write my own.

Comment: Perhaps make clear that the second snippet is psuedo.

Comment: I would take a look at the boost range functionality
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html
along with transform

Comment: @gda2004 yeah.  I am trying to avoid boost as long as possible, though. it def thickens the code/makes it heavier than 'git pull; make' (upvoted though)

Comment: If you have control of the type of `obj_values` you could give it a `operator double()` and you can use the default constructor of the vector giving it two iterators/pointers.

Comment: @bordeo https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3 is a good bet for you if don't want all of boost. It is also header only :) and I believe the ranges ts is built around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `std::transform` is what you are looking for:

```
std::transform(obj_iterable.begin(),obj_iterable.end(),
      std::back_inserter(obj_values), [](auto &x){ return x.value; }
```